# Online Comparison of Two Audio Files

Tags: android, audio-fingerprinting

so i was hoping to compare two audio files, one I have on my android phone, and one which is the exact same that I wish to record through the microphone.

I feel that they should be fairly basic and similar audio enough to be able to get a fairly good comparison, I'm not too worried about accuracy here as long as there is at least some.

After spending like the whole day trying to get my android phone to record a wav file which is compatible with the [musicg library](https://code.google.com/p/musicg/) and not being able to figure out all the examples I've seen on here about easily recording a usable wav file. I was hoping there might be some sort of online API or resource which I could just upload two audio files and obtain a value based on similarity?

I've tried googling but I only come up with artist music sort of comparisons and was hoping someone here might know of something more?

(Please note, I unforutnately won't have anywhere near the amount of time I would need to actually understand any FFT techniques or anything to implement my own)

Comment: If you are willing to send the audio to a server of yours, you can use Python for the audio fingerprinting and recognition: [http://github.com/worldveil/dejavu](http://github.com/worldveil/dejavu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of my project I search on Google for sound comparison libraries too, but I didn't find anything. Fortunately, I found the same `musicg` library and I used it in my project.

It gives good results for solid sounds like door bells, horns, sirens etc but for voice comparing it won't give any expected results.

It takes a long time for big size files but for my project this lib was suitable so I used it. Here is sample code for comparing two wave files.

```
// create a wave object
Wave wave = new Wave(path1);
Wave wave1 = new Wave(path2);
FingerprintSimilarity fingerprintSimilarity = wave.getFingerprintSimilarity(wave1);
float score = fingerprintSimilarity.getScore();
float similarity = fingerprintSimilarity.getSimilarity();
Log.d("Similar sound :", "Score : " + score + "\n  Similarity : "+ similarity);
```

[Link1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grey.hearingaide)
[link2](http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2014/01/compare-two-sounds-in-android.html)